# iOS settings (Privacy -> Location services -> select my app -> change allow access) crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-location

I am really curious about this issue. i have added following things in plist

1.NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription -> YES

2.NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription -> YES

but when I try to change "allow location access" , iOS settings App crashed in iPhone 5(iOS8)..it works on iPhone 4 and 4s (iOS7).can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: If it is the Settings App that crashes (and not your app), then Apple will have to fix this. Try filing a bug report.

Comment: Tell me, why should you give NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription -> YES, when NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription -> YES is already in your plist? The latter itself is enough to allow location detection in background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found answer. we need to give String only for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.. I gave Boolean value for these services..that was cause of issue..

Comment: Not nice, though, that it crashes the Setting app. They need more input validation.